# Value of Raster when we combine 2 raster. (New value not = with old value)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, combine

I have two raster in ArcGis (Number 1 is water level, Number 2 is water depth). I want to combine it to only one raster with two field value. I used Combine Tool in toolbox in ArcGis. After that I got one raster but two field contain value of raster Number 1 and raster Number 2 not = with value of Number 1 and Number 2. Please help me know why and which what order way to have good result.

Comment: Why exactly do you need a combined raster? Generally rasters are used to store one set of values only. The `combine` tool creates only one value, because it makes a new value for all combinations of the two input values. Example: water level = 100 m abvoe sea level, water depth = 1 m --> `combine` assigns the value 1 for this combination.

Comment: Maybe you should create a Raster Dataset? Please explain your problem a bit further.

Comment: Have you looked at stacking the rasters to create a multi band raster?